# Really slow launch time for Sencha/PhoneGap app on android

Tags: android, performance, cordova, sencha-touch, crosswalk

So I have a Sencha Touch/PhoneGap + Crosswalk app whose Android startup duration I have struggled with for a while. Baseline, on first launch is around 10 seconds on a Samsung S3. After poking around and experimenting, I've learned some stuff about app launch time but don't know what I can do with it at the moment, or if there are other techniques to improve launch time.

**So far, I've found:**

1. That completely removing all images on the app (which totals ~20mb) reduces launch time to ~5 seconds.
2. That gutting the Sencha framework code (generated by "sencha app build package") on top of removing images reduces launch time to 2 seconds.
3. Gutting only my Sencha code, however, is negligible on launch time.

Clearly, messing with app size and core Sencha impacts launch time. I've done as much as I know to reduce app size (remove unnecessary images, compress images), and it's helped some, but not much. So I guess **my main questions are:**

1. Are there other notable ways to reduce PhoneGap app package size? Are there components that get added that aren't always necessary? The only other way I've seen is code obfuscation, but going from 40mb to ~37mb would have not much impact on launch time.
2. Is there anything I can do about how long Sencha seems to take to get fully loaded?
3. Am I missing anything else I can do to significantly improve app launch time? I've done a fair amount of research but haven't been able to find anything beyond basic package size; maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms.

Thanks! Any advice here would be much appreciated.

Comment: 40mb Sounds like a lot of images. Can you replace some witha font (Icons). Can you work with vector images instead of PNG. Are you using images as Ext.Img or inside CSS?

Comment: only around 20mb is images; I use font icons, the source of the file size is large photos, which have been heavily optimized with image magick. The rest of the app package is Crosswalk and other stuff that seem to be pre-included with PhoneGap.

Comment: Crosswalk is increasing the size of your application by almost 20MB. I fail to understand how images are increasing your load time (especially if they aren't used in the web view). The Galaxy S3 device is 4 years old (next week).  How do your load times compare on a more recent device?